# Detect and change only "hello" text font-family from editText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have an editText box and when user writes "hello" I want only change "hello" font-family change to italic but others text font-family stay same only change "hello"

```
String detectText, text;
    detectText = "hello";
    text = title.getText().toString();
    detectText.
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: you need a textwatcher (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) , i'm sure some online resouces could guide you to achieving it, try it out and maybe post here if you have any further issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone said, you need a text watcher to be able to make changes when the text is changed. You also need spans to be able to style parts of the text. Here's a way to do it:

```java
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    private static final String KEYWORD = "hello";

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // Remove previous spans.
        for (StyleSpan span : s.getSpans(0, s.length(), StyleSpan.class)) {
            s.removeSpan(span);
        }

        // Add new spans for every occurrence of the keyword.
        int i = 0;
        while (i != -1) {
            i = text.toString().indexOf(KEYWORD, i);
            if (i != -1) {
                s.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), i, i + KEYWORD.length(),
                        Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                i += KEYWORD.length();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The text watcher has three methods called at different times of the editing, but it's only safe to make changes to the text in `afterTextChanged`. There, all previous style spans are removed then the text is scanned to add new ones.

Note that performance might be a problem if you intend to turn this into something a lot more complex, like a syntax highlighter. Right now all spans get readded everytime the user changes a single character.

Comment: Use `ArrayList` and add spans for each word by repeating the whole while loop. Or alternatively you could use regex.

Comment: what should I use if i want more words not just "hello". I want two or more words? Should I use arrayList? I tried but not work.

Comment: Hey you still there? I want to change color too. I tried not work. I tried like edittext.setTextColor but it changes whole all text color. :)

Comment: You need spans if you want to change parts of the text. Use `ForegroundColorSpan` here, just like you used `StyleSpan` before.